# does singleton instance of connection object creates issue in web application

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, singleton

I am using below code snippet to create a singleton instance of Connection object for a web application which will be used by multiple users.

```
static {
        try {
            String driver = PropertyReader.getPropertyReader("driverClassName");        
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

   private static Connection conn = null;
private static synchronized Connection getDBConnection()
    {
         try{
             if(conn == null || conn.isClosed()){
                conn = null;
                String URL = PropertyReader.getPropertyReader("url");
                String userName = PropertyReader.getPropertyReader("username");
                String password = PropertyReader.getPropertyReader("password");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,userName,password);
                logger.info("Preparing Connection..."); 
             }               
             else{
                 logger.info("Returning already prepared connection..");
             }
         }

         catch(Exception e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return conn;
    }
```

This class will return same instance of connection until and unless connection is closed or null.
I suppose same connection will be shared by all users on different machine as it is static one.

If one user is setting auto commit to off to commit couple of statements as transaction, will this create problems for other users by restricting their connection to disable autocommit as well or by commiting their transaction in mid way if one user has used con.commit()?

Comment: You should prefer to use Connection pool..`Connection` is just an JDBC interface..it depends on how it is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will cause problems. They are sharing the same instance, so this statement is wrong

```
If one user is setting auto commit to off to commit couple of statements as transaction, will this create problems for other users by restricting their connection to disable autocommit as well or by commiting their transaction in mid way if one user has used con.commit()?
```

It should read

```
If one user is setting auto commit to off to commit couple of statements as transaction, will this create problems for other users because the connection they are sharing has been set to not autocommit and all of their statements will now become part of the new transaction**
```

Since all the users (threads) are using the same instance, changes made to it by one user will affect the others.

As Shivam Kalra says, connection pools are a better tool. Most probably your web server will already provide them, and if not there are third party libraries.

Comment: thanks Shivam and Sjuan. I was thinking of using the Connection pool myself but before that I just wanted to confirm the transaction issue which has been described in better way by Sjuan.

Answer (score 0):

> will this create problems for other users by restricting their connection to disable autocommit

Yes.

> as well or by commiting their transaction in mid way if one user has used con.commit()?

Yes.

Database connections are not safe for use by multiple threads, and should not in general even be member fields let alone singletons. They should be method-local variables. If you want to economize on creating & destroying them, you must use a connection pool.